# How come my http status code is 0 on my ionic app and heroku?

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, cordova, heroku

SSL is not setup and I have CORs setup on my rails server with the Rake CORS gem. I have this setup for my default headers within my angular app.

```
delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post.Accept = 'application/json, text/javascript';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Content-Type'] = 'application/json; charset=utf-8';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000';
$httpProvider.defaults.headers.common.Accept = 'application/json, text/javascript';
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
```

I am using Ionic/Cordova to talk to my rails server on heroku. On iOS I can successfully make requests to my rails server but with Android I can not.

I created a brand new blank application and I can successfully make requests on the android device when the server is locally (or under ngrok reverse proxy) but I can not make any requests to my rails server hosted on Heroku.

[image: fail status code]

Do you guys have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After busting out wireshark, I was able to figure out the problem. The issue was that I have a CNAME on my DNS pointing to heroku however I mistaken have the "http://" protocol in my CNAME by mistake.

Specifically android webview doesn't follow xhr redirects and halted the request not accepting the response.